# Centering div to screen

Tags: html, css

I can't seem to get the black box to the center of the screen as opposed to the center of the div its inside in.

EDIT: **For clarification, I only want the black box in the center of the results panel not the pink box with it. Also I would also like to keep my javascript intact.** 
EDIT 2: I'm trying to have something like an overlay that popsup in the middle of the screen when a user clicks on the image. Not sure if this is the best way or the best code to achieve that!

Would appreciate if anyone can help.
Here's my attempt: http://jsfiddle.net/BPLcv/1/

HTML

```
<div class="tooltip">
     <div class="description">Here is the big fat description box</div>
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
     <div class="description">Poop</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.tooltip {
    position: relative;
    border: 1px #333 solid;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-image: url('https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSkI2PXYOOOHltHwgIz6xwfuN079IAJDLsmOV68rQNNLCE-GFZ1_aQN89U');
}

.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}

.description {
    position: absolute;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    display: none;
    background-color: black;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 1;
    /* centering???? */
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -150px;
    margin-top: -75px;
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: can you please tell us more about your problem and you wanted to achieve.

Comment: You want the black box in the center of the browser screen and not the center of the "tooltip" div, right? Can javascript/jquery be used?

Comment: @TheOneandOnlyChemistryBlob javascript / jquery can be used.

Comment: @nCore I meant to say that I want the pink box in the current position as relative and just want the black box to be in the middle of the entire result panel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the description/overlay in the middle of the screen, your best bet is to use an element outside of your tooltip-elements, as these are fixed width.

If you have a top-element with `width: 100%`, your centering css wil work for any immidiate children.

**Working fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/BPLcv/4/

Here the overlay is filled with whatever is in the description element of the tooltip you're hovering:

```
overlay.html($(this).find(".description").html());
```

The description class is always hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Check this <kbd>**[Demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BPLcv/2/)**</kbd>

#### CSS

```
body{
    margin:auto;
    width:50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Assign the div of interest id = CenterDiv, then add this css:

```
z-index:10;//remove left:50%
```

Now try adding this function via onload or onclick, etc:

```
function centerDiv() {
    document.getElementById("CenterDiv").style.marginLeft = ((screen.availWidth - 300) 
/ 2)  + 'px';
}
```

The number 300 can be any number that represents the width of your element of interest.

Substituting the width of your element (here, 300px), this function will center an element with absolute position.